# Zend_service_twitter and the list of followers

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, twitter, oauth

I'm developing an application where I sign in using twitter and OAuth. I'm using `Zend_OAuth` and the `zend_service_twitter` classes. The problem is that I want to collect the list of all my followers but when i use the `userFriends()` or the `userFollowers()` methods I only get the last 100 users following me, even if I pass the page parametre to the functions.

I would like to find a way to get all of my followers or at least be able to paginate them 100 by 100 or something like this.

Comment: Can you check what the actual request is doing by digging into the ZF code. CHeck that it is actually sending the param and not ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly the offical documentation, you can pass page parameter to the method:

> The followers() method accepts an array of optional parameters to modify the query.
>
> id specifies the ID or screen name of the user for whom to return a list of followers.
>
> page specifies which page you want to return.

So i should be something like this:

```
$user->followers(array("page" => 1));
```

EDIT:

As I also had this problem and couldn't really figure out why the pagination didn't work, i used a solution like this:

```
$twitter_url =  'https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id='. $userTwitterId;
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($twitter_url));
$followrs = $response['followers_count'];
```